# Show pie chart legend value vertically

Tags: javafx, pie-chart

I have created pie chart as follows

```
ObservableList<PieChart.Data> pieChartData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    if (jsonObject != null){
        pieChartData = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                new PieChart.Data("Mortgage", mortgageValue),
                new PieChart.Data("Security", securityValue),
                new PieChart.Data("Others", remainingValue));
    }

    final PieChart chart = new PieChart(pieChartData);
```

By default **Legend** shown by pie chart is **Horizontal** (Let * as default Legend label)

```
* Mortgage * Security * Others
```

I want to show it vertically in Legend as:

```
* Mortgage
* Security
* Others
```

Is there is any way to show Legend vertically?
Or suggest me any alternative.

Comment: If you move the legend to the left or right, e.g. `chart.setLegendSide(Side.RIGHT);`, does it automatically change to a vertical display, or remain horizontal?

Comment: @James_D While moving it left or right it shows vertically and I tried that (sorry not to mentioned this in question), but as a project requirement I need to show it at bottom and in vertical order(if not possible with this then by any other method).